# In Eclipse, Variables does not show child variables of extended class

Tags: java, eclipse, variables

I have a class:

```
class MyArrayList extends ArrayList {
    public int dog;
    public MyArrayList(int v) {dog = v;}
}
```

I then create one:

```
foo = new MyArrayList(23);
System.out.println("foo.dog is"+foo.dog);
```

I put a breakpoint at the 'System.out.println' line.  When I hit that breakpoint I look at the 'Variables' pane.  There will be line for 'foo' with content assist available, BUT... there is no line which will show the value of foo.dog.  How can I examine the value of foo.dog in the Variables pane?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.  I got impatient.  There is a button called 'show logical structure' (a yellow arrow pointing to a structure).  Click it to see the locals.